# How can I process a specific part of an Image in Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I used copyMakeBorder to create a 100x100x100x100 border around my image. I would like to use cvtColor to convert only  the part of the image that is inside the border to gray, so the border remains bgr, I don't want to have to use copyTo to copy something inside the border on the image, I would like to process the image in place. I looked all over google and there was no specific code example to do this. May I ask someone provide code example.

Comment: You can't have a single image with two or more different pixel formats (well, as far as I know. You could certainly write the format yourself but, ugh, what a mess to parse.) You can of course use gray scale for your border or use bgr where r = g = b for the inner portion, though that may not be an option if you need a larger dynamic range.  Going for two pixel formats in the same image is a mistake though, you need a different solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What Ed.S suggested is right - in opencv you cannot take some ROI from the bigger image and convert it in place from rgb to grayscale not converting whole image:

```
Mat src(1024, 768, CV_8UC3);
src.setTo(Scalar(255, 200, 100));

Mat roi = src(Rect(100, 100, 300, 300));
cvtColor(roi, roi, CV_RGB2GRAY);  // nothing changed, still src is the same after cvtColor
```

What you can do is to perform conversion to grayscale by hand in the selected roi, what does not involve copying, rather that works in place:

```
    Mat src(1024, 768, CV_8UC3);
    src.setTo(cv::Scalar(255, 200, 100));

    cv::imwrite("out.jpg", src);

    Mat roi = src(cv::Rect(100, 100, 300, 300));

    for(int i=0;i<roi.cols;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<roi.rows;j++) {
            cv::Vec3b p = roi.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i);
            unsigned char lumination = (unsigned char)( 0.2126*p[2] + 0.7152*p[1] + 0.0722*p[0]);
            p[0] = p[1] = p [2] = lumination;   
            roi.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i) = p;
        }
```

EDIT: here's a lena example:

```
Mat src = imread("lena.jpg");
Mat roi = src(cv::Rect(src.cols/4, src.cols/4, src.cols/2, src.rows/2));

for(int i=0;i<roi.cols;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<roi.rows;j++) {
        cv::Vec3b p = roi.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i);
        unsigned char lumination = (unsigned char)( 0.2126*p[2] + 0.7152*p[1] + 0.0722*p[0]);
        p[0] = p[1] = p [2] = lumination;   
        roi.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i) = p;
    }
cv::imwrite("out.jpg", src);
```

Result:

[image]